# Can I send signals to different threads

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, x86

Say I have a Thread A, which wants to send signals to Threads B, C and D. Can I do something like this.

```
SendSignalTo( ThreadB, SIGUSR1 );
SendSignalTo( ThreadC, SIGUSR1 );
SendSignalTo( ThreadD, SIGUSR1 );
```

With SIGUSR1 signal handler, defined differently for Thread B, C and D, like as follows.

```
void SIGUSR1_Handler_for_ThreadB(...){...}
void SIGUSR1_Handler_for_ThreadC(...){...}
void SIGUSR1_Handler_for_ThreadD(...){...}
```

And if not, what is the alternative.

Comment: Signals aren't really that great. On Linux, you could use eventfds  for communication and have each thread run an `epoll` loop on its respective fd. This is also great for load balancing, as you can have multiple threads wait for the *same* eventfd, and precisely *one* is guaranteed to wake up.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's actually a very nice solution if you don't mine the non-portability. Great find!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can send a signal to a specific thread using [`pthread_kill()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html), or if you don't mind being GNU-specific, using [`pthread_sigqueue()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_sigqueue.3.html) (which can specify one `int` or `void *` the handler can access via `info->si_value`).

There is only one signal handler per signal for the process. This means that a specific signal will always call the same handler function, no matter which thread it happens to be. If one thread sets a new signal handler, the signal handler will change for all threads.

However, the workaround is trivial: use a per-thread function pointer to define which function the signal handler should call. Just remember the signal handler limitations -- you can only use [async-signal safe functions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html) in a signal handler.

```
/* Simplify by defining the signal handler function type, assume SA_SIGINFO */
typedef void (*signal_handler_t)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);

/* Per-thread variable pointing to the desired function */
static __thread signal_handler_t  thread_handler = NULL;

/* Process-wide actual signal handler */
static void signal_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *context)
{
    signal_handler_t  func;

    func = __sync_fetch_and_or(&thread_handler, (signal_handler_t)0);

    if (func)
            func(signum, info, context);
}
```

The atomic load (`__sync_fetch_and_or()`) allows you to trivially change the per-thread handler using a simple atomic store at any point in time, without even blocking the signal. Switching to function `new_thread_handler` is then

```
    signal_handler_t  func;

    do {
        func = thread_handler;
    } while (!__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&thread_handler, func, new_thread_handler));
```

The `__sync_fetch_and_or()` and the function switch can both be replaced by one C++11-style `__atomic_` call, but I don't have a GCC recent enough yet, so I'm still using the old-style `__sync_` calls.

POSIX also supports *real-time* signals, `SIGRTMIN+0`, `SIGRTMIN+1`, .., `SIGRTMAX`. They have the added benefit that more than one of them can be pending at the same time. They are much better suited for this kind of thing than the traditional signals.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

New to me is the pthread_kill() function that allows you to send signals to threads under the same process.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_kill

Take care to read the notes on the bottom of the page...

> Signal dispositions are process-wide: if a signal handler is installed, the handler will be invoked in the thread thread, but if the disposition of the signal is "stop", "continue", or "terminate", this action will affect the whole process.

How I interpret this is that the process's handler will be called and then you can take appropriate action knowing that the handler was only invoked for that thread, as long as you meet those conditions.